# Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, math, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have to follow the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, which is to:

Initialize the array is_prime so that all the values of the elements will be true. Then, set the value of is_prime[1] to be false (since 1 is NOT prime.)
For I=2 until sqrt(N) set all the multiples of I to false, starting with I*I until N.
Finally, print all the indexes of is_prime that hold the value true.

The problem is it compiles, but it does not print anything.  You do not give an input, it is supposed to display all prime numbers between 1-300.

Here is the code I have developed so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>        //Library functions
#include <math.h>
#include "simpio.h"

#define N 300             //defining constant

void displayPrime(bool checkPrime);         //Function prototypes
bool checkPrime (int I);
bool is_prime[N+1];          //Array decleration

main()                    
{        
         displayPrime(is_prime);

         getchar();      
}

void displayPrime (bool check)          //Function definitions
{
         int I;

         for(I=1; I<N; I++)
         {
                  checkPrime(I);
                  if(is_prime[I]==false)
                  {
                          printf("");
                  }
                  else if(is_prime[I]==true)
                  {
                          printf("%d\n", I);
                  }
         }
}

bool checkPrime (void)
{
         int number1, x;
         double number;

         is_prime[1]=false;

         number=sqrt(N);
         for(number1=2; number1<=number; number1++)
         {
                  for(x=number1; x<=N; x=x+number1)
                  {
                         is_prime[x]=false;
                         return(is_prime[x]);    
                  }        
                  is_prime[number1]=true;                  
                  return(is_prime[number1]);
         }                      
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've posted?  Does it not compile?  Does it run but give surprising results?  For the latter, what input do you give, what results do you expect and what results do you get?

Comment: ok to use sieve first run a function that'll fill an array with 0 or 1 (where i'th cell is 0 if i is non-prime, 1 otherwise) Then just iterate over them and print instead of calling `checkPrime()` every time. I suggest to check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for theoretical and [this link](http://www.hbmeyer.de/eratosiv.htm) for visual understanding

Comment: I discuss this algorithm in an [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) _Programming with Prime Numbers_ at my blog, including C code.

Comment: No, it compiles, but it does not print anything.  You do not give an input, it is supposed to display all prime numbers between 1-300.

Comment: `between 1-300` doubt. `for(I=1; I<N; I++)
         {
                  checkPrime(I);`

Comment: `displayPrime(is_prime);` ??

Comment: what is the question @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Is not to say that If you do not feel strange.

Comment: Here's the first problem `if(I=1)`. Next problem is that when you fix that you don't return anything from the function in that case. A problem after that is that you'll get a division by zero.

Comment: @Art WHy would I get a division by 0 and where

Comment: In the innermost for loop you do something weird with `I` where you set it to false. Then in the next iteration of the loop it does `N/I`. I'm just reporting what I parse from the code, I'm not even trying to figure out if the algorithm makes sense. You should really try to compile with warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the program doesn't print anything? Looks to me like it's going to be an infinite loop.

Consider the loop that does all your work:

```
     number=sqrt(N);
     for(number1=2; number1<=number; number1++)
     {
          // This looks like an infinite loop!
          for(I=number1; I<=N/I; I=I*number1)
          {
              I=false;    
          }        
          if(I==false)
          {
              is_prime[I]=false;  
          }
          else
          {
              is_prime[I]=true;
          }                  
          return(is_prime[I]);
     }
```

That inner loop can't terminate. Say you call the function with I=2. The first time into that loop, `I` gets set to `false` (which is 0). Then the condition is checked again (`I<=N/I`) ... wait, doesn't that give you a divide by 0 error?

The logic in your program is kind of confused. You should split your program into two parts: computing the primes, and then displaying the primes. Structurally, it should look like this:

```
bool is_prime[N+1]

main()
{
    // fill is_prime with true

    // and then compute the primes
    computePrimes()

    // now output primes
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime[i])
            printf(....);
    }
}
```

With that out of the way, you have to write the `computePrimes` method. You have the basic idea with your outer loop, but the logic of your inner loop is incorrect. Consider what would happen if your loops looked like this:

```
for (int number1 = 2; number1 <= sqrt(N); number1++)
{
    for (int x = number1*2; x <= N; x = x + number1)
    {
        is_prime[x] = false;
    }
}
```

There's an optimization opportunity that I purposely didn't include, that you could add later. It wouldn't affect the result, just the speed.

Comment: But that inner loop does not fit with the algorithm

Comment: My following loops does not seem to be working:

         for(number1=2; number1<=number; number1++)
         {
                  for(x=number1; x<=N; x=x+number1)
                  {
                          is_prime[x]=false;
                          return(is_prime[x]);
                  }        
                  is_prime[number1]=true;                  
                  return(is_prime[number1]);
         }  
This still prints nothing but I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Can you read it, I just realized its really messy.  If its too messy I updated the original code

Comment: @MichaelFerashireSilva: change the second loop initialization to: `int x = number1*2`. And don't `return` anything in the loop. All this function does is fill the array. The loop in `main` prints the primes after they're all computed.